# Unmute Video player on volume up button even mute switch is down like Snapchat video player

Tags: ios, swift, video-player

I have tried this code before calling  **Play** function of  video player

```
   do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        }
        catch {
            // report for an error
        }
```

In this way video player play sound even ringer switch is down without raise volume , But what i want to do is

> Allow voice for videos when clicking the raise volume even in mute